# What is the best way to organize Jinja2 templates?

Tags: jinja2

I found the way Jinja2 `extends` works quite inadequate or I'm possibly not using it in the correct way.
I would like to break down my templates folder into smaller, manageable pieces and include them into a bigger page. For example, I would like the `index.html` page to be made up of:

```
header.html
content.html
signup.html
footer.html
```

While my `dashboard.html` would be:

```
header.html
dashboard.html
footer.html
```

I can create a base.html template and include header/footer etc. in it but, that still leaves me with a rather large chunk of html that I don't want. I want as small pieces of html in one file as possible.
Please suggest a way to achieve this. Or guide me to some best practices, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I created a jinja CMS to generate child templates like your index.html and dashboard.html. A child templates holds one or more small html blocks. This html is stored in the db. I use App Engine.

The first version of this CMS can be found here:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5965/review-request-jinja-cms-for-energiekantoor-nl-on-google-app-engine